# How to implement automatic search functionality to my application?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a simple GUI application to manage unknown words while learning a new language. The app which is called Vocabulary is written in C# and it loads/saves words from/into an XML document. Since I have recently switched from Windows to Linux, I am rewriting the app using Python.

Nevertheless, I am having troubles with implementing search functionality to my application. When I enter a word in the text widget, it should automatically be displayed in the listbox. To accomplish what I want the application to do, I know that I should handle text changed event of the text widget.

Here is my original C# method:

```
private void txt_Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txt_Search.Text != "")
    {
        for (int i = listView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var item = listView1.Items[i];
            if (item.Text.ToLower().Contains(txt_Search.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                item.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
                item.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
            }
            else
            {
                listView1.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            listView1.Focus();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        LoadWords();
        RefreshAll();
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            item.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            item.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
        }
    }
}
```

...and here is my Python function so far:

```
def txt_Search_text_changed(self, event = None):

    if self.get_search() != None:

        i = self.listBox.size() - 1

        for x in range(i, 0, -1):
            item = self.listBox.get(0, "end")[i]
            if self.get_search().lower() in item.lower():
                self.listBox.itemconfig(i, {'bg': 'red'})

            else:
                self.listBox.delete(item)

        if len(self.listBox.curselection()) == 1:
            self.listBox.focus()

    else:
        self.load_words()
        self.refresh_all()
        for item in self.listBox.get(0, "end"):
            self.listBox.itemconfig(i, {'bg': 'white'})
```

I don't know what is Python's equivalent for:

`listView1.Items[i];`
`listView1.Items`

Comment: When you say "automatically be displayed in the listbox", do you mean that it should automatically be added to an existing listbox? Or are you saying words are already in a listbox and your search function should simply search through the listbox and highlight the searched-for word?

Comment: It should simply search through the listbox and highlight the searched-for word.

Comment: There's no reason to do `self.listBox.get(0, "end")[i]`. If you read the documentation you'll see that `self.listBox.get(i)` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get all of the items in a listbox with `listBox.get(0, "end")`. Using that list, you can do the search using normal python methods.

Here's an example which uses a variable trace to do the search whenever the value changes:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.search_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.search_var)
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self)
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.listbox.pack(side="left",fill="both", expand=True)

        self.search_var.trace("w", self.autosearch)

        self.listbox.insert("end", "four", "fourteen", "fourty-four", "four hundred")

    def autosearch(self, *args):
        search_string = self.entry.get().lower()
        values = [item.lower() for item in self.listbox.get(0, "end")]

        for index in range(len(values)):
            # reset background to the default
            self.listbox.itemconfigure(index, background="")

        if len(search_string) > 0:
            for index, item in enumerate(values):
                if search_string in item:
                    self.listbox.itemconfigure(index, background="pink")

root = tk.Tk()
Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried to implement your example to my code. Everything works fine, but after searching for an item, all the items stay coloured. How can I overcome the issue?

Comment: @popokatepetl: I can't see your code so I have no idea what to tell you, other than to do what I did in my example and reset the colors.

Comment: It's the same situation with your example. Try entering "hundred" and deleting it right afterwards, the items will stay pink.

Comment: OMG I'm so happy this works, thank you very much once again